# stroke material in black is half transparent, end of stroke not trimmed

Tags: grease-pencil

I would like to draw with the same material as the "stroke" material by default, when you add a grease pencil object, but when I draw, the stroke seems to have transparency and the end of the stroke is not trimmed, although I checked the option in the "stroke" menu.

[image]

Here is the blend file :

https://pasteall.org/blend/ec7049d9f19641e7acb60d3f6f53e4f5
Any advice would be very appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Hello, are you using a stylus to draw ?

Comment: @Gorgious yes I do, there is a slight difference with the pressure, but not enough to have a black stroke like the one by default

Comment: You should uncheck the pressure setting for *strength* then https://i.stack.imgur.com/taJgK.png

Comment: @Gorgious thanks! yes it works better. Would you know how to get a color with its full opacity? The color is a little bit too transparent.

Comment: You are in X-Ray mode, try to go in material preview or disable X-Ray mode (either of those) https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onjhy.png

Comment: @Gorgious great! thank you!

Comment: If you don't mind, what behaviour would you like to see when you talk about "trim stroke ends" ?

Comment: @Gorgious like the end of the stroke object by default, but it works fine now, thanks